# Applying CSS styles to ember.js handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a simple Ember.js app to learn more about JavaScript MVC frameworks. However, it appears applying CSS styles to a view template isn't possible (or rather, I am ignorant of the proper way to do this):

**Without template**

```
<span class="myClass">
Some value
</span>
```

In this case, the style appears properly, as expected.

**With template**

```
<span class="myClass">
<script type="text/x-handlebars>
{{MyApp.someVariable}}
</script>
</span>
```

In this case, the style doesn't seem to be applied at all.

I even tried something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars>
{{MyApp.someVariable classToAdd="myClass"}}
</script>
```

Which creates an even more bizarre output (I can't even find that element in the Chrome developer element tab).

Online tutorials don't mention this issue and I have tried researching other Stackoverflow issues (there are some about applying styles but not exactly like in this situation). Can anyone enlighten me as to what I am not doing properly?

Comment: You're missing a double quote on your `type` attributes and they might need an `id` of some sort so that Ember can find them. Are you saying that the templates aren't being styled after they've been filled in and converted to HTML?

Comment: I do have the double quote in the actual code, just missed it while copying over to stackoverflow. And you are right, the templates aren't being styled after they've been filled with real values and converted to HTML.

Comment: Apparently, you have to put the <script type="text/x-handlebars"... higher in the HTML element hierarchy. Depending on where you wrap the HTML code in the x-handlebars script tags, the rendered styles will be different. Also, classToAdd doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept your own answers, you might have to wait a bit to accept though.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use ClassNames and classNameBindings property of Ember Views. That get the job done most of the time.

You can also try Ember layout property to wrap the template.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to this question in jquery's append() documentation
You need to convert text into html using jQuery:

```
template = Handlebars.compile(..);
html = template(json);
$('body').append($(html)); // <- don't forget to wrap it
```